# How to save into one Excelsheet many (n) dataframes using python without deleting the previous dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

After parsing  eml files and extracting them to create many dataframes, I want to save them to one Excel file.
After saving all my dataframes into the Excel file I still have only the last dataframe among them not all of them in the Sheet.

Someone have an idea how I can solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use sheet name parameter:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

df_1.to_excel(filename, sheet_name='df1')
df_2.to_excel(filename, sheet_name='df2')
```

Comment: Ok I used the pd.DataFrame( ) method and It worked.

Comment: But after saving  all my dataframes (thousand of dataframes) into one excelsheet It took to much time to run. How can I save the dataframes into that excelsheet by chunk to optimize my memory usage ?

Comment: you can use other libraries like Dask for parallel computing or you can use spark.but dask has similar functions like pandas.

Comment: you can also use predefined functions to optimise your code.